# Kubuntu and screen savers

Tags: kubuntu, screensaver

After upgrading to Kubuntu 11.4 I am not able to choose any other screen savers than `Blank screen` and `Random` (which is the same as blank since there are no other screen savers available).

How can I choose other screen savers?

On my other Kubuntu-computer there is a button called `Get new screen savers` or something.

Comment: and you don't have that button anymore i presume?

Comment: Nope, that's the thing, I'm missing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enter this at the terminal:

```
   sudo aptitude search screensaver
   sudo aptitude install [packagename]
```

[image: Screensaver]

You will end up with this installed:

```
   xscreensaver (-data, -data-extra, -gl, -gl-extra) 
   kscreensaver-kde4 & kscreensaver-xsavers-extra-kde4
```